# How can I get the name of a table as a string in kdb+

Tags: kdb

e.g if table is `tbl_trade_jan17`, how can i get a string variable `"tbl_trade_jan17"`? I am afraid i might be missing something very obvious here!
The motive is not to use `get` or `eval` or call table from its name - functional.
The idea is to save the table on the hard disk with the same filename as the name of the table. Also to reference associated tables. e.g `trd_jan17` might also have a `quote_jan17` table and a `sym_jan17` table associated. so if i can get the name `tbl_trade_jan17`, i can then get the names of associated tables by string manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> idea is to save the table on the hard disk with the same filename as the name of the table.

To get a list of tables defined, use `tables`

e.g.

```
tables`. //for the root name-space
```

you can filter with `like`

e.g.

```
t:tables`.
t:t where t like "pattern_*"
```

and then save with `save`

```
save each hsym t //careful
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Question above changed

Correct me if I am wrong but it seems that you want to be able to call your table from the string "tbl_trade_jan17"?
In this case get and value are are interchangeable for this purpose.

```
q)tbl_trade_jan17:([]c:1 2 3;c2:1 2 3)
q)type tbl_trade_jan17 / tbl_trade_jan17 is a table (type 98h)
98h
q)/ to use the string as a variable to retrieve the table:
q)get "tbl_trade_jan17"
c c2
----
1 1
2 2
3 3
q)value "tbl_trade_jan17"
c c2
----
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`string`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/casting/#string) function

```
q) string `tbl_trade_jan17
    "tbl_trade_jan17"
```

Comment: to clarify i need without the backquote aka `string tbl`, i knew how to convert symbol to string

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you are asking - can you provide some more detail on what you are trying to do ?